# Is there a better way of doing data validation in Perl than regex?

Tags: regex, perl, validation

Is there a better way of doing data validation in Perl than regex?

I have Perl code that does string and numeric data validation using complex regex, and this makes code difficult to read and follow, for everyone.

Comment: The only way to untaint tainted data is via regular expressions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel. Use [Regexp::Common](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Regexp::Common) from [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Regexp::Common qw(number);

my $val = '500.345';

print "Good float\n" if $val =~ /^$RE{num}{real}$/;
```

[CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/) is your friend.

Comment: You must anchor your patterns.

Comment: if perl had strong typing..then we wouldnt have to validate ...correct?

Comment: @not-exactly-a-unixhater:  Have a look at Variable::Strongly::Typed or Lexical::Types on CPAN.   If its parameter related then take a look at "signature" related modules.

Comment: @not-exactly-a-unixhater: yes you still had to validate, if you were to store the data in a database. You still had to enforce some kind of CHECK constraints for your business rules ("date of birth must be at least 18 years in the past", "pH value between 0 and 14", etc) . (I doubt that you'd rather implement a distinct datatype or class for all of these rules.). Many databases still can't do this, or only as a last resort-measure against programmer errors.

Answer (score 8):

A common mistake is to cram all your requirements into a single regular expression. This works the first time, but usually you get a regular expression that nobody will understand two weeks down the road.

Don't do that. Use one regular expression per requirement.

Answer (score 7):

There is an absolutely awesome module for parameter validation in perl: [Params::Validate](https://metacpan.org/pod/Params::Validate)

It lets you check your parameters in a clean and nice way. We used it everywhere from the moment we discovered it.

Comment: The URL is 404. Here it is: [Params::Validate](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Params%3A%3AValidate)

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to do validation without regexps. **But** - using regexp doesn't mean you can't make it readable.

There is (often not used) //x flag to regexps, which let's you build *very* readable regexps with comments.

Of course this doesn't mean that you should validate everything with regexps - even if technically possible - it is often insane (think 4KB long regexp for email address validation).

Comment: You could just use http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Email::Valid instead of pasting the 4 KB regex into your code ... **That** would make your code more readable.

Comment: Of course. But it doesn't negate the fact that the regexp exists. And is not a sane solution to the problem at hand.

Answer (score 1):

How you validate data depends on what you are trying to do. If the data merely needs to look like some pattern, that's regex territory. If the data must be an exact value from an enumeration, a hash is better. If a number has to be within a range, the numeric comparisons are the tool you should use.

In general, the answer to this sort of question is "maybe".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure variable values fit a certain pattern, there is no better way than to use the pattern matching facilities of Perl.

On the other hand, if you want to improve a specific pattern, you can ask here for advice.

You can make your own programs easier to follow by abstracting away such regular expressions and use facilities such as [Regexp::Common](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Regexp::Common).

Answer (score 0):

There might be.

Sometimes a regular expression is the best approach, sometimes it is not. You have to examine it on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: This is not helpful. Adding an example of each case would be helpful.

Comment: That would require that the OP provided the cases in the first place. I can't suggest good solutions for sanity checking vaguely described data formats.